# Kali VM hangs when TL-WN722N is selected as a USB Device for VirtualBox VM

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed **Kali VM on VirtualBox**. I am running this on a **Macbook (OSX El Capitan)** and have bought a new **wireless adapter - TL-WN722N** to use with the VM. So I connect the adapter to the USB port, then start my Kali VM. The VM opens up fine.

So then I go to: 
**VirtualBox VM > Devices > USB** , where I find **ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN** option. Next, guessing that I need to select this to allow my Kali VM to start using it, I click on the option.

**This is where my Kali VM just hangs!!** In fact, later I observe, that the green light on the adapter itself is not glowing (seems like it wasn't glowing from the beginning itself).

I have tried the below several times, with no respite.

- restarting the VM
- unplugging & plugging the adapter

How can I get my adapter to be working with my Kali VM? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post an answer for whoever was experiencing the same issue as I was. Here's how I fixed it.

1. **Checked my VirtualBox Settings**:

   VirtualBox Manager (Kali VM selected) > Settings > Ports

   Here I found "Enable USB Controller" was checked but USB 1.1 (OHCI) Controller was selected. Got me thinking, I'm plugging in my wireless adapter into a USB2.0 port, so probably the next option USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller should have been selected. I select it and OK. The **setting gets selected and saved, but throws an alert ("VirtualBox Extension Pack needed!**")
2. **Install VirtualBox Extension Pack**

   I download the extension pack from here - http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/20279-virtualbox_extension_pack, and install it. **Quite easily, the alert is now gone.**
3. **Start the Kali VM and again select the ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN option**

   On starting the VM, I again go to **VirtualBox VM > Devices > USB and select ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN. This time it works!**

Final results:

- The Green Light on the Adapter is glowing again.
- 'lsusb' command in the terminal shows my adapter

  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
- 'iwconfig' command in the terminal shows 'wlan0' in 'Managed Mode'.